# prevent replacing previous image with new one (android)

Tags: android, image, android-image, environment, fileoutputstream

i am working on wallpaper app in which i am downloading image, but i am having problem of image replacing.

when ever i download new image it gets replaced with previous one.

this is my code:

```
public void saveImageToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String dirname = "/Amazing Wallpapers/";

        File myDir = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + dirname);

        myDir.mkdirs();

        String str = currentUrl.substring(
                currentUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1,
                currentUrl.length());

        String fname = "Wallpaper-" + str +  ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(
                    _context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved).replace("#",
                            "\"" + pref.getGalleryName() + "\""),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Wallpaper saved to:" + file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the current `Date` time in milliseconds as unique identifier to your `File`. Like this:

```
 String str = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I tested your code and it is working.

Comment: OK, it works, but generates new problem, problem is now i can save same image many times. but i don't want to save same image many times if it already exist

Comment: @android question Then, you have to think about some way of knowing which files are already saved and check it. The position of the page of your ViewPager, for example. Or the file name.